# How to use promise, .then.. properly?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

First of all, I'm sorry that I couldn't come up with a better title for this post. Also, I'm a beginner in nodejs. I have a problem for which I am hoping to find answer. Please help me and thank you so much.

I am trying to create a collection and insert data into it and retrieve the same data that has been inserted in the same code. This piece of code `dbo.collection(nameofCollection).insertMany(data)` inserts the data into the collection if exists already and if it doesn't exist, it will create the collection and then insert.

This is the code that I've written for this task :

```
var excel = require('excel4node');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongodb = require('mongodb')
const mdb = mongodb.MongoClient;
mdb.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/", async function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err
    const nameCollection = "tempCollection"
    const dbo = db.db("reports")  

    const data = [
      {
        empID : "001ev",
        empName : "xyz",
        salary : 20000
        },
      {
        empID : "00234",
        empName : "abc",
        salary : 10000
      },
      {
        empID : "11345",
        empName : "pqr",
        salary : 15000
      }
    ];


    dbo.collection(nameCollection).insertMany(data, function(err, res) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("Number of documents inserted: " + res.insertedCount);
      console.log("first")
    })


     const records = await dbo.collection(nameCollection).find({}, { projection: { _id: 0} }).toArray()
     console.log(records)
     console.log("second")
})
```

Now, the issue that I'm facing with this code is that, when there is no collection in the data base, it is creating one and inserting the data. Up to that it is working fine. But, the thing is, find query is executing first and then insert is executing. And if that collection already exists then it is working fine, it is inserting the data and then find query is executing.

So, to put it short, if there is no collection with the name, nameCollection; find query is executed first, which returns []. Then the collection is created and insertion of data is happening. But, why is this happening, although in my code I wrote to create the collection first, insert data and then retrieve it?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of asynchronous runtime. There is no guarantee that *find* function will be executed the last.

try adding this:

```
try {
  const res = await dbo.collection(nameCollection).insertMany(data);
  console.log("Number of documents inserted: " + res.insertedCount);
  console.log("first");

  const records = await dbo.collection(nameCollection).find({}, { projection: { _id: 0} }).toArray()
  console.log(records)
  console.log("second")
} catch (error) {
  throw err;
}
```

In this case you can omit try/catch block since it does not have impact on error handling.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. It's working fine now!